# eBGP redistribution on Mikrotik CCR

Tags: router, bgp, isp

I need to redistribute BGP to my client.

I have 2 transit providers, and my own AS with my own IP space. Now my client wants to advertise his own AS and IPs using us as his sole transit provider.

I have a single Mikrotik CCR Router. Is it possible to do this with my router? If so, can you give an example configuration?

Comment: Will you advertise a default route to your client, or full tables, or something in between?

Comment: want to give default route to my client....  Do i have ask my provider to allow something to redistribute BGP to my client?

Comment: I have to confess that I have never configured this brand of router before. But a quick read through the manual shows its not particularly hard *once you are clear on what you want to do*. So first:  I assume you are already peering with your upstream providers.  Can you post that configuration? Second: you should contact them to see if they will allow you to advertise client routes and ASNs.  They may be filtering updates from you.  Finally, it is important that you filter your own clients so they do not announce wrong routes.  They can literally break the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already have eBGP up and running between you and your transit providers, and that you have only a default route, not the full internet BGP table. I assume also that you and your customer each have a public AS and a public subnet.

So, I will mention only minimum needed config to enable you advertise your customer AS and subnet, which can apply also for your customer, noting the router model they are using.

Take a look at  http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Routing/BGP and set the following :

```
remote-address a.b.c.d <== IP address of customer peer router running BGP with you
remote-as xxxxx <== customer public AS number
network x.y.z.0/24 <== any specific subnets from your AS that need to be advertised to your customer
default-originate always <== provide default route to your customer via BGP (your customer should not use this command on their end)
```

Again, note that this is a minimum config that will allow you to initiate BGP session with your customer and advertise their AS and subnets to your upstream providers, there are other elements that should be added, e.g. I prefer creating a VRF for the customer on your router, also, you could adjust local-preference or AS prepending in order to select which of your 2 transit providers would be primary preferred by BGP and which would be secondary, among other BGP features.